# Do default Tranactions in postgresql provide any benefit when only the last statement is writing?

Tags: sql, postgresql, transactions

I just learned that [in Postgresql the default transaction isolation level is "Read committed"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html). I'm very used to MySQLs "REPEATABLE READ" isolation level. In postgresql by my understanding this means in a default transaction "two successive SELECT commands can see different data". With that in mind, is there any benefit to transactions when only the last statement in the transaction is writing?

The transaction does not prevent you from data changing between statements, the only benefit I see is rolling the transaction back on failure. But if only one writing statement exists at the end, then that would happen anyway.

To make a bit more clear what I'm referring to, lets take a generic simple sequence of (pseudo) queries to a table:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
SELECT userId FROM users WHERE username = "the provided username"
INSERT INTO activites (activity, user_fk) VALUES ("posted on SO", userId)
COMMIT
```

In this sequence and any general sequence of statments where only the last statement is writing, is there a benefit in postgresql to using a transaction with the default isolation level?

Bonus question, is there any overhead from it?

Comment: The point of a transaction is to safeguard that multiple steps all complete successfully or not at all. By defining an explit transaction you are acquiring a shared lock on the row in table users, meaning no other transaction can modify that same row until your transaction has committed (or rolled back). If you don't *need* this then the only purpose your example transaction serves is to impact the concurrency of your database.

Comment: The default depends on the default for your database (server) configuration. Check the configuration for your default

Comment: @Stu did you look at the linked documentation? It does not aquire a lock, running the select statement twice could return different results.

Comment: @FrankHeikens yes and no. There is a defined default in the documentation, ofc you can override it on database level.

Comment: What is it you are comparing? One isolation level to a different isolation level?  One isolation level versus no explicit transaction at all?

Comment: There is a default default_transaction_isolation value, but the real value depends on the person that set up the server. And the one who started the database connection. That’s why defaults cannot act as a reliable and stable fixed setting: they can change. When you need certain behavior, you set the configuration for your connection to guarantee this behavior.

Comment: For your statements it does not really matter as the `userId` from the `SELECT` is not going to used in the `INSERT`. I'm sure there is some small incremental overhead, but I would say it is not as much as writing out he WAL entry which is going to happen in either case.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between `READ COMMITTED` and `REPEATABLE READ` is that the former takes a new database snapshot for each statement, while the latter takes a snapshot only for the first SQL statement and uses that snapshot for the whole transaction. This implies that `REPEATABLE READ` actually performs better that `READ COMMITTED`, since it takes fewer snapshots.

The disadvantage of `REPEATABLE READ` is that you can get serialization errors. That does not affect your example, but if you had an `UPDATE` instead of an `INSERT`, it could be that the row you are trying to update has been modified by a concurrent transaction since the snapshot was taken. The serialization error that causes would mean that you have to repeat the transaction. Another disadvantage of `REPEATABLE READ` transactions is that a long-running read-only transaction can hinder the progress of `VACUUM`, which it wouldn't do in `READ COMMITTED` mode.

For read-only transactions or transactions like the one you are showing, `REPEATABLE READ` is often the better isolation level. The nice thing about `READ COMMITTED` is that you can get no serialization errors apart from deadlocks.

To explicitly answer your question: there is no advantage to running the statement from your example in a single transaction. You may as well use the default autocommit mode to run them in separate transactions.

Incidentally, the SQL standard decrees that the default transaction isolation level be `SERIALIZABLE`, but I don't know any database that implements that.

Comment: Thank you for the extensive answer. the part about repeatable read having a single snapshot is postgresql specific right? It mentions in the documentation that it has a stricter repeatable read isolation level than the default sql standard and by my understanding the default sql standard would not have the snapshot as it could have different results for range reads.